# HDFS block size and replication

Tags: hdfs

I have a file called employee.txt.The size of that  file is 66 MB.

We know that default HDFS block size is 64 MB.

So, There is going to be two blocks for employee.txt as the size of it is greater than 64 MB

employee.txt = block A + block B

So, There are two blocks.

For block A it is 64 MB,So there is no problem at all ..

For block B it is 2 MB, So what will happen to the reamining 62 MB of block B.Does it kept as empty?

I would like to know what happens to that unoccupied space  for block B.

Comment: Can some body answer this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HDFS blocks are logical blocks that sits on Physical file system.  So when your second block uses just 8 MB, it only consumes that much space from the underlying file system, rest of the disk space will be left free.